# TypeScript 4.8 and axios: response is now of type "unknown"

Tags: typescript, axios, typescript4.0

I have an Ionic React app written in TypeScript.  Upon attempting to upgrade to 4.8 this morning, I am getting `Object is of type 'unknown'.` for Axios responses.

- axios 0.27.2
- typescript 4.8.2

This code worked fine in 4.7 but TypeScript 4.8 refuses to build my app.

Here's the code at issue:

```
const handleErrorsPostAuth = (error: AxiosError) => {
  if (error?.response) {
    // Object is of type 'unknown' for the line below.
    if (error.response.data.errors[0]) {
      // Object is of type 'unknown' for the line below.
      throw new Error(error.response.data.errors[0].detail);
    }
    throw new Error(error.response.toString());
  }
  throw new Error(error.message);
};
```

I read the [TypeScript 4.8 release notes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-8/) and found under breaking changes that [lib.d.ts updates](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-8/#lib-d-ts-updates) included:

> While TypeScript strives to avoid major breaks, even small changes in
> the built-in libraries can cause issues. We don’t expect major breaks
> as a result of DOM and lib.d.ts updates, but one notable change is
> that the cause property on Errors now has the type unknown instead of
> Error.

My issue is with `response`, not `cause`, so I'm not sure if this is the issue I'm experiencing.

Here's the `AxiosResponse` interface from axios **index.d.ts**:

```
export interface AxiosResponse<T = any, D = any>  {
  data: T;
  status: number;
  statusText: string;
  headers: AxiosResponseHeaders;
  config: AxiosRequestConfig<D>;
  request?: any;
}
```

I tried to add a check with `instanceof` like this:

```
if (error?.response && error.response instanceof AxiosResponse) {
```

But this doesn't work because `AxiosResponse` is an interface and it seems there is no way to check whether an object implements an interface in TypeScript, only whether an object is of a given type.

So, how do I correctly check for an axios response now?  This may be obvious but I don't really understand how the axios types work-- I think I need to narrow the type to ensure I have an AxiosResponse and not unknown, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As we can see here AxiosError is a Generic https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/bdf493cf8b84eb3e3440e72d5725ba0f138e0451/index.d.ts#L276

Where T is unknown by default. T is used to create the type of the Response
https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/bdf493cf8b84eb3e3440e72d5725ba0f138e0451/index.d.ts#L288

So you should be able to do something like this:

```
type MyErrorResponse = {
  errors: {detail: string}[]
}


const handleErrorsPostAuth = (error: AxiosError<MyErrorResponse>) => {
  if (error?.response) {
    // Object is of type 'unknown' for the line below.
    if (error.response.data.errors[0]) {
      // Object is of type 'unknown' for the line below.
      throw new Error(error.response.data.errors[0].detail);
    }
    throw new Error(error.response.toString());
  }
  throw new Error(error.message);
};
```